# how to return the features that used in decision tree that created by DecisionTreeClassifier in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, feature-selection

i want to do feature selection on my data set by CART and C4.5 decision tree. In such a way that apply decision tree on data set and then extract the features that decision tree algorithm use to create the tree. so i need return the features that use in the created tree. i use "DecisionTreeClassifier" in  sklearn.tree module. i need a method or function to give me (return) the features that used in created tree!! to use this features as more important features in main modulation algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach the problem similar to the below:

I assume you have the train (x_train, y_train) and test (x_test, y_test) sets.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

tree_clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = tree_clf1.predict(x_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print("\n\nAccuracy:{:,.2f}%".format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))
print("Precision:{:,.2f}%".format(precision_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))
print("Recall:{:,.2f}%".format(recall_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))
print("F1-Score:{:,.2f}%".format(f1_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))

feature_importances = DataFrame(tree_clf1.feature_importances_,
                                index = x_train.columns,
                                columns['importance']).sort_values('importance', 
                                                                    ascending=False)

print(feature_importances)
```

Below is an example output, shows which features are important for your classification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is exammple for getting top 5 important features in decesion tree.

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
decesionTreeModel = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

decesionTreeModel.fit(X_train2, y_train2)

most_features_frame = pd.DataFrame(
    data=decesionTreeModel.feature_importances_,
    columns=["importance"],
    index=X_train2.columns,
).sort_values(by=["importance"], ascending=False)

# print(most_features_frame)
top_5_feature = most_features_frame.index[:5]
top_5_feature_list = [i for i in top_5_feature]
print(top_5_feature_list)
```